# Parameter error with Type-GraphQL - No type for parameter?

Tags: node.js, graphql-js, typegraphql

I am getting this error but am unsure as to what exactly is wrong because it follows the same format with the other resolvers I've created. This is the error:

```
`Error: You need to provide explicit type for Resolver#`getMultipleSomething parameter #2
```

This is my resolver:

```
@Resolver(() => Object)
export default class Resolver{
    constructor(
        private readonly service: Service
    ){}

    @Query(() => Object)
    async getSomething(@Arg('id') id : number) : Promise<Object>  {
        return await this.service.getSomething(id);
    }

    @Query(() => [Object])
    async getMultipleSomething(@Arg('page') page : number, @Arg('per_page') per_page : number, @Arg('stringArray') stringArray : string[])  {
        return await this.service.getSomethings(page, per_page, stringArray);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `@Arg('stringArray', type => [string]) stringArray : string[])`

Ref: https://github.com/MichalLytek/type-graphql/issues/37#issuecomment-407664643